# Worksheet Audit Log of changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a script which provides me with an Audit Log of changes made on my Data Tab (I would like to provide the user access to make one off changes and therefore don't want to completely lock and protect the tab).

However, i have several other Macros and buttons which alter the data tab, however, i would like it to be such that these changes (made by other macros) are not captured in my Audit Log.

Essentially, is there a way i can have it such that `IF` other macros are called, don't update audit log by automatically going to `Exit Sub` . Or something like that.

See Audit Log Script below,
Other buttons can be anything from (fluctuate Data by x% or a reset button)

```
Dim PreVal

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'This sets our previous value once we have selected the cell value to change
    PreVal = Target.Value
End Sub
    
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastRow
    
    'If we change the cell we selected then the worksheet change event is triggered
    If Target.Value <> PreVal Then
    
        LastRow = Worksheets("Logged Changes").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'If the new value of the cell is not the same a previous value then logging of details begins
        Worksheets("Logged Changes").Cells(LastRow, 2).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
        Application.UserName & " changed cell " & Target.Address _
        & " from " & PreVal & " to " & Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Application.EnableEvents = False` when starting procedures and `Application.EnableEvents = True` when they are finished, which allows you to control how Excel reacts to events, including `Worksheet_Change`?

Comment: Yup all other Modules have the mentioned code at the start and end of the scripts

Comment: In this case, when you run other procedures, reaction to events is suppressed, Worksheet_Change is not run when you change cells with the script, and in the log should not write anything. Or is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a work around - probably not the most efficient or "nicest" way - but it seems to work.

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("Macro").Value = "Running"

    'Rest of Macro1 goes here

Range("Macro").ClearContents

End Sub

'Macro2 (The macro embedded in my sheet) would start with

If Range("Macro").Value = "Running" Then Exit Sub

    'Rest of Macro2


``
```

Comment: If `EnableEvents` doesn't work then there's something wrong with your excel install.